# Sort Items in mongoDB using distance from a desired point

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

**Database**
MongoDB on Azure with Cosmos DB (so the Mongo version will be 3.6)

**Scenario:**
I wish to show to the user in a mobile app, the items are linked to a supplier which have coordinates deep in the document structure. I would like to display the items to the user in the app sorted by distance and show the distance (I do not wish to filter only the close ones).

**Items Collection:**

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "name": "items 1",
  "supplierId": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "others fields": etc.
},{
  "_id": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "name": "items 2",
  "supplierId": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "others fields": etc.
}, etc
```

Suppliers Collection:

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "name": "Supplier A",
  "Address": {"position": {lat: ##.######, lon: ##.##########}},
  "others fields": etc.
},{
  "_id": {"$oid": "########################"},
  "name": "Supplier B",
  "Address": {"position": {lat: ##.######, lon: ##.##########}},
  "others fields": etc.
}, etc
```

The query should take in the coordinates of the end user and return the following:

```
{
  Item: "Item 1",
  Supplier: "Supplier A",
  DistanceInKm: 1.7
},{
  Item: "Item 2",
  Supplier: "Supplier A",
  DistanceInKm: 1.7
},{
  Item: "Item 3",
  Supplier: "Supplier B",
  DistanceInKm: 3.2
},{
  Item: "Item 4",
  Supplier: "Supplier C",
  DistanceInKm: 4.4
},{
  Item: "Item 5",
  Supplier: "Supplier C",
  DistanceInKm: 4.4
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot query by location when your location is given as `{"position": {lat: ##.######, lon: ##.##########}}`

See [GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) how MongoDB stores spatial data. When your location are given as GeoJSON  then you can use [Geospatial Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/), in your case it would be `$nearSphere` or `$geoNear`

Comment: Can I do this on the fly in the aggregate query?

Comment: No, because these spatial queries require a [2dsphere Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)